# What's another way to say "my learnings"?

Tags: synonyms

Refer to the title.

Another word, wording or phrase to say:

> learnings

For example, if I had a list of things that I had learned and I wanted to write "my learnings" as the title. So the question is what are the alternatives because it just doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: You are right. "My learnings" is not idiomatic. You could say "my studies", or "the things I learned".

Comment: 'Learning' is an uncountable noun, not pluralised, idiomatically. 'Teachings' is possible, but not learnings. 'My studies' is one way of conveying what one has learned through study.

Comment: Could one say wisdom? Or is wisdom more of a quality rather than the act acquiring knowledge?

Comment: _Learning_ is countable among teachers of education: things a kid should have learned after a particular class hour are _learnings_. Outside this jargon, uncountable.

Comment: Related: [When did "learnings" become an accepted countable noun?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/450248).

Answer (score 1):

What's another way to say “my learnings”?  my **lessons**

> Suggested alternatives include lessons learned, “things one learned” –
>   or simply **lessons** – discoveries, findings, insights, and takeaways.

lessons [wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/learnings)

Comment: Lessons can mean things you've learnt or things you have taught other people.

Answer (score 1):

You could say *my discoveries*. (Per [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discoveries), *discoveries* can be used as a noun to mean, quite logically, 'something that has been discovered.')

Answer (score 1):

In many situations, you could describe these as your **takeaways.** [Collins defines it as:](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/takeaway)

> an important idea or fact to be remembered, usually one arising from a meeting or discussion

Comment: It seems a largely _Guardian_-specific sense, looking at the examples.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Collins seems to think it's more common in British English, but (as an AmE speaker) I don't see it as unusual.

Comment: It's new to me, in spite of living near Manchester.

Answer (score 0):

*Learnings* is fairly common these days in management consulting and corporate training circles.  If that's your audience, you can just use **Learnings** as your title, unless you need to distinguish between your learnings and those of others.

If you want something more "classic", you could use **Knowledge Gained**, since corporate training sessions are often styled as *Knowledge Transfer*.

BTW, it's a term that greatly annoys the [Linguistic Purists](http://blog.jeffreymcmanus.com/157/learnings-is-a-stupid-stupid-word/) and other people with too much time on their hands.  But you probably know this.

Comment: I found it helpful but I'm not sure it's really the answer I was looking for. Anyway, I guess your theory is correct!

Comment: Because it's NOT common or present at all in corporate training "circles" or anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

What about "findings" ? "Learnings" reminds me of a record book 25 years back. I was doing my apprenticeship and I had to fill the record book with the things I learnt every week. There is also another expression like "vocation learnt".