# When did "learnings" become an accepted countable noun?

Tags: countable-nouns

"Learnings"?  In 2006, it was a [joke word](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0443453/), meant to suggest crude ESL.

In 2007, it's actually being used in the [New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2007/04/05/business/media/05adco.html).  Was that the black day when it changed over?

NYT excerpt:

> “We’re going to learn so much about our readers,” Mr. Smith said of the online-only issue. “We’ll take the **learnings** and apply them to the rest of our business.”

Comment: In the excerpt, the word appears within a quotation. The excerpt consequently does not show that the editors of NYT endorse such usage.

Answer (score 3):

I share with you the jocular nuance of the word. However, a quick Google NGrams search shows that some time in the mid 1920's it started to become very popular very quickly and has been slowly reducing in frequency since a peak in the 1950's.

[image: NGrams chart of learnings]

A perusal of the hits shows that it's been used in the same manner, things that have been learned, all these years.

It has always sounded 'off' to me, like you said  uneducated or like a goofy neologism that would never really catch on. And yet, it caught on a while ago.

Comment: Eek, foolish of me to not think of checking NGrams.  I was alive for the trailing edge of “learnings”’s popularity, but just don’t remember it.

Comment: @Malvolio I look at the graph and have a hard time believing it because I feel like it was only in the past 10 years that corporate speak started using it. But then you look at the examples and the old examples are just as cringeworthy.

Answer (score 2):

Although the Ngram chart in Mitch's answer provides a heartening view of the decline of *learnings* in published texts included in the Google Books database (from the bad old days of the 1950s through about 2008), a more up-to-date look at the Ngram chart for *learnings* (starting, as Mitch's chart does, in 1910 but continuing through 2019) shows that the word has been on the upswing since about 1990 and that it has really begun to pick up steam in the past ten years:

[image]

This may reflect, in part, the vogue that *learnings* has enjoyed in business-speak in recent years, as MBAs—the same people who gave us "If you have to pose the *ask*, you can't afford the *spend*"—have embraced the notion that *teachings* beget *learnings*. I spend a lot of time editing business articles, and I can tell you that the enthusiasm for *learnings* in that sector shows no sign of abating. We're still in the early stages of a second wave at this point, but a wave it appears to be.

Comment: God save the MBAs

Comment: Ah, the same MBAs that gave us us the verb "[to leverage](https://web.archive.org/web/20130906075000/http://irritablevowel.com/2012/03/14/5-bullshit-words-that-make-me-want-to-hurt-you#:~:text=1.%20Leverage)"?

Answer (score 0):

I have been an editor on Chinese language translated documents in the early 2000s. After several years of doing this I have gleaned insight into how they think and common word usages. The use of "learnings" instead of "lessons" I believe is something that has crossed over into our English lexicon with the advent of Chinese (in this case) using words that just "seem wrong." And I believe "learnings" is just one such word that has been introduced into the English language is such a way.

Comment: Hi Gregory, welcome to EL&U. This is an interesting speculation, but at EL&U we're not looking for *authoritative, detailed answers*. Can you [edit] your answer to provide a published example of a Chinese translation using "learnings" *before* the NYT did? For further guidance, see [answer] and take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)